SpringBoot - My project is using a database in memory, and I don't know how to stop doing that and change to an actual persistent db
I have created a Spring project using a h2 database (in memory) to work with it while I was starting with the project. Now, I want to work with persistent data as my project is done. The problem it, I can't switch and I don't see where the problem is. These are my application.properties:
spring.application.name=picoopspring

#Database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/picoopspring
spring.datasource.username=johndoe
spring.datasource.password=johndoe
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
  
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

This is my pom.xml:

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

I
I have the database created in my mysql, with no tables on it. The logs are the next ones:
2024-05-10T19:41:43.115+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] project.picoop.PicoopApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

2024-05-10T19:41:44.320+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.

2024-05-10T19:41:44.370+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 44 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.

2024-05-10T19:41:45.180+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)

2024-05-10T19:41:45.200+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

2024-05-10T19:41:45.200+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]

2024-05-10T19:41:45.316+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

2024-05-10T19:41:45.319+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2146 ms

2024-05-10T19:41:45.469+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

2024-05-10T19:41:45.734+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:7f78d327-0c69-4c8a-8962-3481c091e42a user=SA

2024-05-10T19:41:45.735+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

2024-05-10T19:41:45.804+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]

2024-05-10T19:41:46.035+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.4.Final

2024-05-10T19:41:46.140+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled

2024-05-10T19:41:46.465+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer

2024-05-10T19:41:47.242+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)

2024-05-10T19:41:47.281+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

2024-05-10T19:41:47.602+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.QueryEnhancerFactory     : Hibernate is in classpath; If applicable, HQL parser will be used.

2024-05-10T19:41:48.668+02:00  WARN 15620 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning

2024-05-10T19:41:49.894+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@19cc697c, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@33012e6f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@d88d9d7, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7280785f, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@7593716d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@37bafef8, project.picoop.auth.JWTAuthFilter@592fbd8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5d38758a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4acae4c7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4086e003, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1b12c870, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7c2d4398, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@75bbeb89]

2024-05-10T19:41:50.443+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''

2024-05-10T19:41:50.458+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] project.picoop.PicoopApplication         : Started PicoopApplication in 7.706 seconds (process running for 8.105)

As I understand, this log says the database is created in spring project memory:
2024-05-10T19:41:45.734+02:00  INFO 15620 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:7f78d327-0c69-4c8a-8962-3481c091e42a user=SA
What I'm doing wrong here?
If it works, SA is the name I gave when I first started the application, so I suppose, application.properties have not been readed since then. The route file is: src/main/resources/application.properties

If really is your application.properties what is wit the additional whitespace at the beginning of each line? Remove it. ALso make sure it is in the right place.

Have you tried removing the h2 dependency ?
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>


just removed h2 dependency. Now, it says:
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Have you tried the check that M. Deinum tells you?

Yes, I have, but I have discovered that even new spring projects arent working on my pc, I don't know why

because you have to configure them.
configurations change depending on the version of java, and spring-boot. what version of spring boot and java are you using? 3.2.2 with java 17 ? Do you use intelliJ as your ide? From what I read in the properties file, I understand that you want to use the mysql db? correct? have you installed it locally?

1 . Just Removed the h2 maven dependancies from your pom.xml file .
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


remove  spring.h2.console.enabled=true from application.properties file


You added h2 database dependency in your pom.xml file. H2 is an in-memory database, please remove that dependency and it will work fine.
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

Also remove the property spring.h2.console.enabled=true as there is no need of it. You may use below properties for standard SQL queries and to log values
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace


The problems, as some of the response stated, was on the h2 dependency.
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

Getting rid of it was the solution.

You can also change the scope of the h2 dependency to 'test' if by any chance you want to use it for test purpose.
